# Change merge css name generated

Tags: magento-1.9

In order to refresh my client browser with the last styles, I want to change the name of the generated files when I merge them.

What... where that name is generated?

I merge the css with System > Configuration > Developer > Css Settings > Merge CSS Files to Yes.

It generate a css like 9128734598173458912.css, but it's always the same name, and I want to change it each time I merge the css even the content doesn't change.

UPDATE

@xMageStore give me a good clue, but I think my solution is

`Mage/Code/Model/Design/Package.php 
     public function getMergedCssUrl($files){...}`

Maybe @xMageStore solution is better to add a variable after each file, like `styles.css?version=1.1` It's a good way to refresh the client browser

I need to check more to find what's the best solution

Comment: Magento 1.9 doesn't have a dedicated way that you can merge styles built into the framework, can you explain your set up in more detail? are you using a css pre-processor like `sass` or `less`? What theme are you using? Is it a custom theme, one of the built in themes or something that has been purchased?

Comment: If you clear the CSS/JS Cache, the files will have an update to the [Last Modified Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) Which will force browsers to re-download them & I think that accomplishes your goal.

Comment: @circlesix - I think the OP is referring to the config setting to [Merge CSS Files](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/201-optimizing-magento/how-to-merge-css-files-in-magento)..

Comment: Good call, think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I rewrite `getMergedCssUrl` method in `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package`, to automatically generate new name each time the css change I used:

```
 // merge into target file
        $olderTimestamp = '';
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if ($olderTimestamp < filemtime($file)) {
                $olderTimestamp = filemtime($file);
            }
        }
        $targetFilename = md5(implode(',', $files) . "|{$hostname}|{$port}|{$olderTimestamp}") . '.css';
```

But special metion to @xMageStore, because I think your answer can be usefull if the css or Js isn't merged.

Answer (score 1):

@oootramas answer is very elegant, but I think it could be even further improved upon. Just do

```
$timestampString = '';
 foreach ($files as $file) {
     $timestampString .= filemtime($file);
 }
 $targetFilename = md5(implode(',', $files) . "|{$hostname}|{$port}|{$timestampString}") . '.css';
```

Above code will take into account the filemtime of **every** CSS file, instead of the filemtime of just the oldest file.

That way you get a different hash if you edit a newer CSS file, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is way to change name of merge css/js files. You can see `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` file and function name is `getCssJsHtml()`
Hope it will help you!

Comment: Good point, but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for... not sure, yet

Comment: This function is used for naming the merged css/js so you can add the custom name here for the css/js.